# $watch Listener Not Triggered When ng-maxlength Used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

I have a directive that basically watches the value of element.

This element has `ng-maxlength` attribute which is set to 150. When I pass the 150 characters, the `$watch` is no longer triggered. Besides, when I remove the whole text with ctrl + x, the `$watch` is again not triggered.

**Input Element**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="company.fullName" name="companyFullName" required ng-maxlength="150" ng-input-validate />
```

**Directive**

```
enlabApp.directive('ngInputValidate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(function () { return ctrl.$modelValue; }, function (value) {
                 console.log('test');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I remove the `ng-maxlength` directive, the problem goes away.

Comment: try remove ng-maxlength and use the HTML attribute maxlength.

Comment: That is because your model becomes invalid when it exceeds and its value will be null. What exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, but when I select the whole text and remove it, $watch is not triggered again. This is the problem.

Comment: When you remove everything its value becomes undefined again.. previous value was also undefined so it does not trigger. This is because it actually lies in the validation triggered by angular when you use `ng-maxlength`. INstead return `return element[0].value;` from your watch and see. http://plnkr.co/edit/BgIhog?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved my problem. Please write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Sure i will add it. You can use `ctrl.$viewValue` as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `ng-maxlength=150` which mean angular will perform a validation for the number of characters and it will update the `$modelValue` accordingly. Meaning when it is invalid (if length exceeds) `$modelValue` will be `undefined` and then you remove the value by doing `ctl-x` and then digest cycle runs and again model value becomes `undefined` since there is no value present and there is no difference from the previous value and the watcher does not trigger (Watcher will trigger only if the `modelValue` becomes dirty).

So use `$viewValue` or `element[0].value` (which i wont suggest). So do:-

```
        scope.$watch(function () { 
          return ctrl.$viewValue; 
        }, function (value) {
          console.log('Triggered');
        });
```

- $viewValue: Actual string value in the view.
- $modelValue: The value in the model, that the control is bound to.

*Remember that using `ng-minlength` is only for validation it does not restrict user from entering/pasting more characters, if you want to restrict the `minlength` attribute is the way to go*

Also note that you do not have to register a watch on `ngModel` you can use [`$viewChangeListeners`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) as well instead of creating an additional watch.

> Array of functions to execute whenever the view value has changed. It is called with no arguments, and its return value is ignored. This can be used in place of additional $watches against the model value.

```
ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){//... });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$watch`, you can use `element.bind` "input" event. like see:

```
  element.bind "input", ->
    ctrl.$modelValue
```

if you update ctrl, you must use $scope.$apply() for updating view:

```
  element.bind "input", ->
    $scope.$apply ->
      ctrl.$modelValue
```

this is my example where I use it:

```
link: ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) ->

  element.bind "focus", ->
    if not ngModelController.pristineBlur and not ngModelController.dirtyBlur
      ngModelController.pristineFocus = on
    else 
      ngModelController.dirtyFocus = on
      ngModelController.pristineBlur = off
      ngModelController.dirtyBlur = off
    ngModelController.focus = on
    updateController()

  element.bind "blur", ->
    if ngModelController.pristineFocus
      ngModelController.pristineBlur = on
      ngModelController.pristineFocus = off
    else
      ngModelController.dirtyBlur = on
      ngModelController.dirtyFocus = off
    ngModelController.focus = off
    updateController()

  element.bind "input", ->
    updateController()

  updateController = ->
    $scope.$apply ->
      ngModelController.pristineFocusOrValid = ( ngModelController.pristineFocus and ngModelController.pristineFocus or ngModelController.pristineFocus and ngModelController.$valid ) or ( ngModelController.focus and ngModelController.$valid )
      ngModelController.minlengthWarning = ( ( ngModelController.pristineBlur or ngModelController.dirtyFocus or ngModelController.dirtyBlur ) and ngModelController.$viewValue and ngModelController.$invalid ) or ngModelController.dirtyFocus and ngModelController.$invalid
      ngModelController.isRequiredError = ( ngModelController.pristineBlur or ngModelController.dirtyBlur ) and not ngModelController.focus and not ngModelController.$viewValue
```